# How do I remove parts of strings to leave the information I want?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that appears in my text files. I am trying to isolate a certain part of it.

The string is

```
!Image: Software: C3750-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M, 12.2(25)SED, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
```

I need to grab the `C3750-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M, 12.2(25)SED` part, but the issue is that this part changes depending on the file that is being read. So I'm guessing I need a reverse regex (??) which selects only the text not matched. Below is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
$fulldir = "/location/";
opendir(DIR, $fulldir);
my @files = grep {$_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..'} readdir DIR;
closedir(DIR);
foreach my $configs (@files) {
    open FH, "$fulldir/$configs" or die $!;
    while (<FH>) {
        if ($_ =~ m/!Image: Software:.*/) {
            my $text = $_;
            $text = Regex goes here i think : D
            print "$configs is running $text\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should always `use strict`

Comment: Also¸ please use `perltidy`. This makes my eyes burn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all the lines end with ', RELEASE SOFTWARE'? In this case you can use the following regex:

```
m/^(.+), RELEASE SOFTWARE/
```

The part that you want will then be in $1.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your while loop with this one:

```
while (<FH>) {
   if (($text) = (/\!Image: Software: (.+), RELEASE SOFTWARE/)) {
      print "$configs is running $text\n";
   }
}
```